Need Powershell query to export database table data from remote datastore using API endpoint and username and password. Need that data into CSV format
# Define credentials and API endpoint
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$apiUrl = "https://apiurl.com"
# Create the authentication header
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("${username}:${password}")))
$headers = @{
   Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"
}
# Make the API call
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers
# Process the response (assuming JSON response)
$responseData = $response | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json
# Export the results to a CSV file
$responseData | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\test\Desktop\acd automation\apioutput.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Using above Powershell, but I am getting the data count output. I am looking for actually data with row and column.

What does $($response | ConvertTo-Json) look like on it's own?

With this information, I can only quide you to generally flatten the json object. Please Edit your question and add a [mcve] of your Json file.
